# what does -zxvf mean in tar -zxvf <filename>?

Tags: linux, tar

I have seen on many websites commands like this what does the "-zxvf" or the similar commands stand for?

```
tar -zxvf <filename>
 tar xvf <filename>
```

Comment: `info tar` or `man tar`

Comment: Read the software's description, i.e. `tar --help` or `man tar`. Really. Off topic as well, since not programming related. Let's close this, fast.

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://superuser.com/ or even http://serverfault.com/ . Please try to ask only questions that are related to programming/software development and programming tools on this site.

Comment: Refer linux man pages for all information.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

- `z` means (un)z̲ip.
- `x` means ex̲tract files from the archive.
- `v` means print the filenames v̲erbosely.
- `f` means the following argument is a f̱ilename.

For more details, see `tar`'s [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Answer (score 14):

Instead of wading through the description of all the options, you can jump to `3.4.3 Short Options Cross Reference` under the `info tar` command.

`x` means `--extract`. `v` means `--verbose`. `f` means `--file`. `z` means `--gzip`. You can combine one-letter arguments together, and `f` takes an argument, the filename. There is something you have to watch out for:

> Short options' letters may be clumped together, but you are not
>   required to do this (as compared to old options; see below).  When
>   short options are clumped as a set, use one (single) dash for them
>   all, e.g., ''tar' -cvf'.  Only the last option in such a set is
>   allowed to have an argument(1).
>
> ---
>
> This old way of writing 'tar' options can surprise even experienced
>   users.  For example, the two commands:
>
> ```
>  tar cfz archive.tar.gz file
>  tar -cfz archive.tar.gz file
> ```
>
> are quite different.  The first example uses 'archive.tar.gz' as the
>   value for option 'f' and recognizes the option 'z'.  The second
>   example, however, uses 'z' as the value for option 'f' -- probably not
>   what was intended.